# Apply price rule to variants of a configurable product?

Tags: magento, configurable

Our apparel store is built with configurable products.  We'd like to create a Catalog Price Rule that targets only specific variants of a configurable product.  For example, all 'Guys' shirts.

It doesn't appear that this is possible out of the box with Magento unless I'm missing something.  Has anyone found a way to do something like this just using Mage configuration?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, but would be ideal for the [proposed dedicated Magento StackExchange site (link)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento?referrer=HFqQT3Qeb2X27y6ehRWkiw2).

Comment: Thanks Ben!  I'm committed.  Will move it over then (can I move over now?)

Comment: Not yet. When the site goes beta.

Comment: Ben, you want to put this on the StackExchange beta site now?

Comment: Yes! Ask it over there and link here.

Comment: You need to see that post with the same problem. In cart we have only configurable products with children products. And we need to apply sales rules from children to parent(configurable) product
[Answer for you](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86733/23550)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this functionality isn't available at the moment out of the box. You can set different prices for product variants (under associated products in configurable product), but you can not do the same via catalog price rules.

There are couple of extensions though, that could help you out (like [SCP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html), etc.)